# c/c++ linting or format check code documentation

Tags: c++, clang, static-analysis, clang-tidy

Is there anyway of using clang-tidy or cppcheck or any other tool to check for missing documentation including file header comment to class members. I am assuming doxygen.

Comment: assuming doxygen? afaik doxygen can warn you about missing documentation

Answer (score 1):

Look into doxygen output log. It has all missing documentation warnings in it. All you need to have as far as I know is a file header in doxygen as it will skip completely non documented files.